# Angular2 template container in root component?

Tags: angular

I want to use a Modal inside my Angular2 project in almost any component. I created a app dialog-component with a selector `<app-dialog></app-dialog>` and i can set options using `@Input()` and `@Output()` parameters.

I can use the `<app-dialog></app-dialog>` container in all component templates, but isn't there a smarter way? I think placing it in the root `app.component.html` would be fine, but it's not working.

I want to show a modal from a modalService for example, opening up the app-dialog.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: ng-bootstrap modal does what you want, you could check how they do that: [link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)

Comment: Angular2 Material components also contain a modal component. You can at least use it as example for your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Service` with `Observable`, in Modal bind to that `Observable`, then `@Inject() Service` to consumer `@Component` which should post all changes (`@Input`) to the modal through that service. If you need `@Output`, then you need second `Observable`... For more information read [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)